# Proof verification: a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{N}$ with a single element is bounded above and below.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, natural-numbers

Proposition: A nonempty subset $S$ of $\mathbb{N}$ with a single element $\eta$ is bounded above and below.

**Proof.** Suppose $S$ does not have an upper bound. Then, there exists no number $u$ s.t. $u \gt \eta$. But $\eta + 1 > \eta$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, $S$ is bounded above.

Suppose $S$ does not have a lower bound. Then, there exists no number $\ell$ s.t. $\eta > \ell$. But $\eta > \eta - 1$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, $S$ is bounded below. $\square$

Would this be satisfactory or am I missing something? I'm attempting to learn how to write acceptable proofs in real analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's OK, but there is no need to use contradiction.  You can just say $\eta$ is both an upper bound and a lower bound (because $\eta \le \eta$ and $\eta \ge \eta$).

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Comment: As an aside: doesn't the idea of bound imply one of distance? If it is simultaneously the upper and the lower bound, doesn't it somehow fail to perform an act of bounding? Or does this fact just trivially follow from the definition?

Comment: Definition: $b$ is an upper bound for set $S$ if for all $s \in S$, $s \le b$.